# Why in batch norm we don't restrict beta to be positive

Tags: neural-networks, batch-normalization

From this answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/437474/346940 seems that batch norm scales the standardized input by a factor $ \beta $... why don't we restrict this $\beta$ to be greater than zero?

if with one gradient update we pass from a $\beta > 0$ but very close to zero, to one small and negative, the input of the following layer will be flipped all of a sudden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The updates to $\beta$ are done to improve the loss. Assuming the gradient descent is working (no software bugs, the step size is small enough), then the result of $\beta$ becoming smaller and eventually negative is that the model's loss is decreasing and the model is improving.

Neural networks are compositions of many parameters, so considering a single parameter in isolation does not give the full picture of how changing it will change the network. At the same time that $\beta$ is being updated to minimize the loss, so too are all of the other parameters in the model. So it could be the case that $\beta$ is getting smaller, or even changing sign, because the weights before or after it are also changing sign or growing larger.

This observation, a weight getting larger and smaller, and possibly changing sign, is related to [identifiability](/questions/tagged/identifiability), because the signs and magnitudes of a single weight are not unique but instead operate in conjunction with the signs and magnitudes of the weights before and after it. See: [Can we use MLE to estimate Neural Network weights?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145902/can-we-use-mle-to-estimate-neural-network-weights/145907#145907) The phenomenon of  is not unique to the weights and biases of the batch normalization layer. It could also happen in an ordinary neural network with several layers.

Comment: yes idk y but i thought that beta was special wrt all the other weights of the nets, because I was estimating the gradient, so I had to sample beta from a gaussian, so half the samples where positive and half negative, and that made everything working very bad

Comment: $\beta$ is usually initialized at 1, but otherwise it’s a normal weight updated with backprop.